# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBarCode' of undefined (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to implement a webcam decoder into my MVC4 project, i have everything near enough working except for one issue. During debugging i notice that when i click on the decode button i get an error in the google chromes debugger for javascript, stating the following "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBarCode' of undefined ". I presume it has something to do with the format of  onclick method (See below) however after numerous tries at formatting it i still get the same error. I have included the Js file and my cshtml view as well

QR.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Webcam";
}

        <script>
            //$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#webcam").scriptcam({
                    path:'~/Scripts/',
                    readBarCodes: 'QR_CODE',
                    onError: onError,
                    cornerRadius: 0,
                    onWebcamReady: onWebcamReady
                });
            //});

            function onError(errorId, errorMsg) {
                alert(errorMsg);
            }
            function changeCamera() {
                $.scriptcam.changeCamera($('#cameraNames').val());
            }
            function onWebcamReady(cameraNames, camera, microphoneNames, microphone, volume) {
                $.each(cameraNames, function (index, text) {
                    $('#cameraNames').append($('<option></option>').val(index).html(text))
                });
                $('#cameraNames').val(camera);
            }
        </script> 


        <div style="width:330px;float:left;">
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="~/Scripts/scriptcam.swf" width="320" height="240" id="webcam" style="visibility: visible;"><param name="menu" value="false"><param name="wmode" value="direct"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="flashvars" value="width=320&amp;height=240&amp;chatWindow=chatWindow&amp;path=&amp;zoom=1&amp;zoomChat=1&amp;rotate=0&amp;skewX=0&amp;skewY=0&amp;flip=0&amp;noFlashFound=%3Cp%3EYou%20need%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.adobe.com%2Fgo%2Fgetflashplayer%22%3EAdobe%20Flash%20Player%2011.7%3C%2Fa%3E%20to%20use%20this%20software.%3Cbr%2F%3EPlease%20click%20on%20the%20link%20to%20download%20the%20installer.%3C%2Fp%3E&amp;onError=function%20onError(errorId%2CerrorMsg)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09alert(errorMsg)%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D&amp;cornerRadius=0&amp;onWebcamReady=function%20onWebcamReady(cameraNames%2Ccamera%2CmicrophoneNames%2Cmicrophone%2Cvolume)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%24.each(cameraNames%2C%20function(index%2C%20text)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%24('%23cameraNames').append(%20%24('%3Coption%3E%3C%2Foption%3E').val(index).html(text)%20)%0A%09%09%09%09%7D)%3B%20%0A%09%09%09%09%24('%23cameraNames').val(camera)%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D&amp;id=webcam"></object>
            <div style="margin:5px;">
                <img src="webcamlogo.png" style="vertical-align:text-top">
                <select id="cameraNames" size="1" onchange="changeCamera()" style="width:245px;font-size:10px;height:25px;">
                <option value="0">In Built Camera</option></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:135px;float:left;">
            <p><button class="btn btn-small" id="btn1" onclick="$('#decoded').text($.scriptcam.getBarCode());">Decode image</button></p>
        </div>
        <div style="width:200px;float:left;">
            <p id="decoded"></p>
        </div>
```

Scriptcam.js

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.scriptcam=function(options) {
        // merge passed options with default values
        var opts=$.extend({}, $.fn.scriptcam.defaults, options);
        // off we go
        return this.each(function() {
            // add flash to div
            opts.id=this.id; // add id of plugin to the options structure
            data=opts; // pass options to jquery internal data field to make them available to the outside world
            data.path=decodeURIComponent(data.path); // convert URI back to normal string
            $('#'+opts.id).html(opts.noFlashFound); // inject no flash found message
            // forward incoming flash movie calls to outgoing functions
            $.scriptcam.SC_promptWillShow=data.promptWillShow;
            $.scriptcam.SC_fileReady=data.fileReady;
            $.scriptcam.SC_fileConversionStarted=data.fileConversionStarted;
            $.scriptcam.SC_onMotion=data.onMotion;
            $.scriptcam.SC_onError=data.onError;
            $.scriptcam.SC_onHandLeft=data.onHandLeft;
            $.scriptcam.SC_onHandRight=data.onHandRight;
            $.scriptcam.SC_onWebcamReady=data.onWebcamReady;
            $.scriptcam.SC_connected=data.connected;
            $.scriptcam.SC_onPictureAsBase64=data.onPictureAsBase64;
            $.scriptcam.SC_disconnected=data.disconnected;
            $.scriptcam.SC_setVolume=data.setVolume;
            $.scriptcam.SC_timeLeft=data.timeLeft;
            $.scriptcam.SC_userLeft=data.userLeft;
            $.scriptcam.SC_userJoined=data.userJoined;
            $.scriptcam.SC_addChatText=function(value) {
                value = value.replace(":{", '<img src="'+data.path+'angry.gif" width="16" height="16" class="smiley"/>');
                value = value.replace(":-{", '<img src="'+data.path+'angry.gif" width="16" height="16" class="smiley"/>');
                value = value.replace(":)", '<img src="'+data.path+'smile.gif" width="16" height="16" class="smiley"/>');
                value = value.replace(":-)", '<img src="'+data.path+'smile.gif" width="16" height="16" class="smiley"/>');
                value = value.replace(":D", '<img src="'+data.path+'biggrin.gif" width="16" height="16" class="smiley"/>');
                value = value.replace(":-D", '<img src="'+data.path+'biggrin.gif" width="16" height="16" class="smiley"/>');
                value = value.replace(":O", '<img src="'+data.path+'ohmy.gif" width="16" height="16" class="smiley"/>');
                value = value.replace(":-O", '<img src="'+data.path+'ohmy.gif" width="16" height="16" class="smiley"/>');
                value = value.replace(":(", '<img src="'+data.path+'sad.gif" width="16" height="16" class="smiley"/>');
                value = value.replace(":-(", '<img src="'+data.path+'sad.gif" width="16" height="16" class="smiley"/>');
                value = value.replace(":p", '<img src="'+data.path+'tongue.gif" width="16" height="16" class="smiley"/>');
                value = value.replace(":-p", '<img src="'+data.path+'tongue.gif" width="16" height="16" class="smiley"/>');
                value = value.replace(";)", '<img src="'+data.path+'wink.gif" width="16" height="16" class="smiley"/>');
                value = value.replace(";-)", '<img src="'+data.path+'wink.gif" width="16" height="16" class="smiley"/>');
                $('#'+data.chatWindow).append(value+'<br/>');
                $('#'+data.chatWindow).animate({ scrollTop: $('#'+data.chatWindow).prop("scrollHeight") - $('#'+data.chatWindow).height() }, 100);
            }
            if (opts.canvasHeight && opts.canvasHeight) {
                var newWidth=opts.canvasWidth;
                var newHeight=opts.canvasHeight;
            }
            else {
                // no canvas dimensions given, make our own horizontal layout
                var newWidth=opts.width*opts.zoom;
                var newHeight=opts.height*opts.zoom;
                if (opts.chatRoom) {
                    newWidth=(opts.width*opts.zoom)+(opts.width*opts.zoomChat)+5; // make room for two horizontal video windows with a margin of 5
                    opts.posX=(opts.width*opts.zoom)+5;
                    newHeight=opts.height*Math.max(opts.zoom,opts.zoomChat);
                };
            }
            // make new dimensions are not below minimum flash size
            if (newWidth < 215) {
                newWidth=215;
            }
            if (newHeight < 138) {
                newHeight=138;
            }
            if (opts.rotate!=0 || opts.skewX!=0 || opts.skewY!=0 || opts.flip!=0 || opts.zoom!=1 || opts.zoomChat!=1) {
                // no GPU acceleration
                var params = {
                    menu: 'false',
                    wmode: 'window',
                    allowScriptAccess: 'always',
                    allowFullScreen: 'true'
                };
            }
            else {
                // GPU acceleration when no filter is used
                var params = {
                    menu: 'false',
                    wmode: 'direct',
                    allowScriptAccess: 'always',
                    allowFullScreen: 'true'
                };
            };
            // Escape all values contained in the flashVars (IE needs this)
            for (var key in opts) {
                opts[key] = encodeURIComponent(opts[key]);
            };
            if (fileExists(decodeURIComponent(data.path)+'scriptcam.swf')) {
                swfobject.embedSWF(decodeURIComponent(data.path)+'scriptcam.swf', opts.id, newWidth, newHeight, '11.6', false, opts, params);
            }
            else {
                alert(decodeURIComponent(data.path)+'scriptcam.swf not found, please check the path parameter');
            }
        });
    };

    function fileExists(url) {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('HEAD', url, false);
        http.send();
        return http.status==200;
    }

    $.scriptcam={};

    // outgoing functions (calling the flash movie)

    $.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64=function() {
        return $('#'+data.id).get(0).SC_getFrameAsBase64();
    }

    $.scriptcam.version=function() {
        return $('#'+data.id).get(0).SC_version();
    }

    $.scriptcam.hardwareacceleration=function() {
        return $('#'+data.id).get(0).SC_hardwareacceleration();
    }

    $.scriptcam.getMotionParameters=function() {
        $('#'+data.id).get(0).SC_getMotionParameters();
    }

    $.scriptcam.getBarCode=function() {
        return $('#'+data.id).get(0).SC_getBarCode();
    }

    $.scriptcam.startRecording=function() {
        $('#'+data.id).get(0).SC_startRecording();
    }

    $.scriptcam.pauseRecording=function() {
        $('#'+data.id).get(0).SC_pauseRecording();
    }

    $.scriptcam.resumeRecording=function() {
        $('#'+data.id).get(0).SC_resumeRecording();
    }

    $.scriptcam.closeCamera=function() {
        $('#'+data.id).get(0).SC_closeCamera();
    }

    $.scriptcam.changeVolume=function(value) {
        $('#'+data.id).get(0).SC_changeVolume(value);
    }

    $.scriptcam.sendMessage=function(value) {
        $('#'+data.id).get(0).SC_sendMessage(value);
    }

    $.scriptcam.playMP3=function(value) {
        $('#'+data.id).get(0).SC_playMP3(value);
    }

    $.scriptcam.changeCamera=function(value) {
        $('#'+data.id).get(0).SC_changeCamera(value);
    }

    $.scriptcam.changeMicrophone=function(value) {
        $('#'+data.id).get(0).SC_changeMicrophone(value);
    }

    // set javascript default values (flash default values are managed in the swf file)
    $.fn.scriptcam.defaults={
        width:320,
        height:240,
        chatWindow:'chatWindow',
        path:'',
        zoom:1,
        zoomChat:1,
        rotate:0,
        skewX:0,
        skewY:0,
        flip:0,
        noFlashFound:'<p>You need <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">Adobe Flash Player 11.7</a> to use this software.<br/>Please click on the link to download the installer.</p>'
    };
})(jQuery);

// incoming functions (calls coming from flash) - must be public and forward calls to the scriptcam plugin

function SC_onError(errorId,errorMsg) {
    $.scriptcam.SC_onError(errorId,errorMsg);
}

function SC_fileReady(fileName) {
    $.scriptcam.SC_fileReady(fileName);
}

function SC_fileConversionStarted(fileName) {
    $.scriptcam.SC_fileConversionStarted(fileName);
}

function SC_onMotion(decodedString) {
    $.scriptcam.SC_onMotion(decodedString);
}

function SC_promptWillShow() {
    $.scriptcam.SC_promptWillShow();
}
function SC_onHandLeft() {
    $.scriptcam.SC_onHandLeft();
}
function SC_onHandRight() {
    $.scriptcam.SC_onHandRight();
}
function SC_onWebcamReady(cameraNames,camera,microphoneNames,microphone) {
    $.scriptcam.SC_onWebcamReady(cameraNames,camera,microphoneNames,microphone);
}

function SC_onPictureAsBase64(value) {
    $.scriptcam.SC_onPictureAsBase64(value);
}

function SC_connected() {
    $.scriptcam.SC_connected();
}

function SC_disconnected() {
    $.scriptcam.SC_disconnected();
}

function SC_setVolume(value) {
    $.scriptcam.SC_setVolume(value);
}

function SC_onMotion(motion,brightness,color,motionx,motiony) {
    $.scriptcam.SC_onMotion(motion,brightness,color,motionx,motiony);
}

function SC_timeLeft(value) {
    $.scriptcam.SC_timeLeft(value);
}

function SC_addChatText(value) {
    $.scriptcam.SC_addChatText(value);
}

function SC_userJoined(value) {
    $.scriptcam.SC_userJoined(value);
}

function SC_userLeft(value) {
    $.scriptcam.SC_userLeft(value);
}
```

UPDATE

Basically what im trying to acheive https://www.scriptcam.com/demo_5.cfm

Upon further inspection i found that this works no problem on webforms but in MVC its a mess. Anyone have any luck implementing in MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scriptcam was ditched due to more problems occuring, decided to use the JSQRcode code instead, i appreciate your help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't modified the `scriptcam` library then my guess is that yes, the issues surrounds your `onclick` handler or the possibility that $ is not defined in the the current scope. I would advise against writing JS code in html markup as you cannot debug it (using chrome dev tools for example).

Instead, define the click handler in JS, i.e:

```
$("#yourButtonId").click(function(){
    // Handle click...
});
```

The next thing i would advise is that you break up your function calls and use the JS debugger to figure out what is actually undefined. Is it the $?, try using JQuery.scriptcam... instead, or as Jason mentioned try calling it like a function. Finally, make sure the scripts have loaded correctly first before trying to call the given methods.

Chrome dev tools (F12) is your friend.

Comment: thank you for this :) however im still getting no success changing it to what you suggested.... Has it got anything to do with me changing the swf and js paths? in the source code from scriptcam it only states scriptcam.js where as i changed it to ~/scripts/scriptcam.js    Sorry if its a bit confusing my jquery experience is only new :)

Comment: tbh, i have never used the scriptcam library. Could you possibly provide an example of your code (using [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com)/[jsbin](http://www.jsbin.com)). This would go along way towards someone being able to assist you. Please update your question when you do. :)

Comment: this is the link i got all my source code from https://www.scriptcam.com/demo_5.cfm

Comment: I had a look at the demo code from the download, and it is one huge mess! All the resources are dumped into the base folder (not organised at all). You are probably missing a required resource or script, which is causing the main script to throw an exception before it has a chance to register the function you are trying to call. You need to download and render the example locally and figure out if you have included everything that is required.in your project.

Comment: Hi @SpearOne, i understand what you mean, further investigation with me and my colleague resortedin us ditching the scriptcam and going for the JSQR source code, it was much easier to implement, less code and i have full control and view of each js file. i must close this question.